# can't add multicast group

Tags: erlang, udp, ipv6, multicast

Trying to add multicast group for ipv6, but it returns error. don't understand the problem. with ipv4 it works fine

```
(test_client@127.0.0.1)1> {ok, S} = gen_udp:open(3333, [binary, {active, false}, {ip, {65342,0,0,0,0,0,34048,9029}}, inet6, {multicast_loop, false}]).
{ok,#Port<0.1587>}

(test_client@127.0.0.1)4> inet:setopts(S, [{add_membership, {{65342,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}}}]).
{error,einval}
```

unfortunately this topic in erlang docs is badly documented

also have tried with addrreses like ff3c: , ff32:

**UPDATE**
i've looked into Erlang/OTP 18.2 source code, there is using function `prim_inet:is_sockopt_val(add_membership, {{65280,0,0,0,0,0,34048,9029}, {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}})`

and it always return false, because in prim_inet:type_value_2/2 we have type ip, value `{_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_}` and it waits only for ipv4 `{_,_,_,_}`.
on the one hand i know why can't add membership with ipv6 when open socket, but on other hand what to do is opened question

Comment: In the third digit, `3` currently means `Realm Local`, which is yet undefined, pending an RFC to define it; you may want to use `2` for `Admin local`. Also, in the fourth digit, the high-order bit must be `0` (cannot be `8` or larger), and if the `R` bit is set the `P` bit must be set, and if the `P` bit is set, the `T` bit must be set (the digit must be `0`, `1`, `3`, or `7`). Having the 'R' bit set means that you are embedding an RP address. Likely, you only want the 'T' bit set (fourth digit is `1`) to indicate a transient, not permanent, well known address. That would mean using `ff21`.

Comment: @RonMaupin thanks for the answer :)
i will fix it. but the second problem is that otp expects only ipv4 addr

Comment: IPv6 and IPv4 are two completely separate layer-3 protocols. Anything expecting an IPv4 address needs an IPv4 address, not an IPv6 address. I don't know about what you are using, but you must have an IPv6 network, including IPv6 multicast clients and source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like Erlang's driver has implemented `IPV6_ADD_MEMBERSHIP`, but it does have raw support so you could construct it yourself. A problem with this approach is that you are hard coding things usually defined in header files, so your solution wont be very portable.

```
-module(unssmraw).
-export([test/0]).


test() ->
  Port = 57100,
  Mad = <<65340:16,0:16,0:16,0:16,0:16,0:16,34048:16,9029:16>>,
  Ifindx = <<3:64/native>>,
  Ip6 = 41,
  Ip6am = 20,

  {ok, Sock} = gen_udp:open(Port, [{reuseaddr,true}, inet6, binary]),
  R3 = inet:setopts(Sock, [{raw, Ip6, Ip6am, <<Mad/binary, Ifindx/binary>> }]),
  io:format("ssm ok? ~w ~n", [R3]),
  receive
    {udp, S, A, Pr, Pk} -> io:format("watcher sees: Socket ~p Address ~p Port ~p Packet ~p ~n", [S, A, Pr, Pk]) end.
```

Example test sender:

```
echo hi | socat - UDP6-SENDTO:\"ff3c::8500:2345\":57100
```

Example run:

```
$ erl
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.0.1] [source-761e467] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V8.0.1  (abort with ^G)
1> unssmraw:test().
ssm ok? ok 
watcher sees: Socket #Port<0.453> Address {65152,0,0,0,47734,16383,65066,
                                           19977} Port 43511 Packet <<"hi\n">>  
ok
```

## Notes on my hardcoded values

- How to find the interface index used in `Ifindx`:

  As of OTP 22 [net:if_name2index](http://erlang.org/doc/man/net.html#if_name2index-1) is available to call. A language neutral description is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609721/how-to-determine-value-for-ipv6mr-interface-field-of-ipv6-mreq-structure). I used a 64-bit since that is the size of an int on my system and it is an int in mreq in my in6.h.)
- `Ip6`'s value is from in.h
- `Ip6am` is IPV6_ADD_MEMBERSHIP from in6.h.

Comment: For me, I had to add a `native` endianess specifier for the interface index, i.e.: `Ifindx = <<3:64/native>>`

Also, note that you can find the interface index (from its textual name) in Erlang using `net:if_name2index/1`.

Comment: Good points, I've added the native since I think it should make it correct on both endians. Since net:if_name2index is new in OTP 22 I've added it to the notes but not tried to implement it in the example.